# OMS Heartbeat query for when a server is down

Tags: azure, azure-oms

How can i set an alert in OMS when a server is powered off or is not available? I have searched on google but the alerts either dont work or too many get sent . I need the alert to be generated as soon as the server goes offline

Answer (score 1):

i found out myself

```
Heartbeat | summarize LastHeartbeat = max(TimeGenerated) by Computer | where Computer == "server1" | where LastHeartbeat < ago(5m)
```